# sed -i copies the original text, taking extra space. Is there another way?

Tags: sed

I have a script that backup a table with the size of 300GiB to `back.sql`,
then copies it to `bak_copy.sql`,
then `sed -i 's/original/copy/g bak_copy.sql`.

Today I found out that `sed -i` starts creating another file while replacing the stream,
so the script makes trice a storage size of the original `back.sql` at some point.

Is there a better option then?
Will `sed 's/original/copy/g' back.sql > bak_copy.sql` be equally safe and fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

`sed 's/original/copy/g' back.sql > bak_copy.sql` - reads a file, changes contents, writes into different file.

`sed -i 's/original/copy/g' bak_copy.sql` - reads a file, changes contents, writes into temporary file. Once done, replaces the original file with temporary.